# ForEach Array value in jQuery JSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, foreach

Okay, i want to process another javascript request foreach value returned inside a JSON response from a jQuery Request, Here's the current code i'm using for this request

```
function waitForEvents(){
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/functions/ajax.php?func=feed&old_msg_id="+old_msg_id,

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                **//Foreach json repsonse['msg_id'] call another function**
                setTimeout('waitForEvents()',"1000");  
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Error:" + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout('waitForEvents()',"15000");       
            },
});
};
```

for each json response variable ['msg_id'] i want to call another javascript function but don't know how to process the array using a foreach in javascript, any idea how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already using jQuery, you can use the $.each function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$.each(json.msg_id, function (index, value) {
    // Do something with value here, e.g.
    alert('Value ' + index + ' is ' value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple for loop, likely faster than for each

```
function myfunction(id){
    alert("myid:"+id):
}

var i=0;
for (i=0; i< json.length;i++){
    var thisId = json[i].msg_id;
    myfunction(thisId);
}
```

simpler:

```
function myfunction(id){
    alert("myid:"+id):
}

var i=0;
for (i=0; i< json.length;i++){
     myfunction(json[i].msg_id);
}
```

since you asked:

```
function checkArrayElements(element, index, array) {
     console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
     var myId = element.msg_id;
};
json.forEach(checkArrayElements);
```

and discussion in case older browsers where not implimented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach  so you can do that

Comment: I make the assumption that msg_id is in each element at the root level.